# Is it possible to call action from components function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have question is there any possibility to call actions from function or event handler? I use React-Redux.

Example:

```js
    export class Page extends React.Component {

    onSomething() {
        this.props.onAdd();
      };

    render() {
        return (
             <div>
               <List
                 SomeMethod={this.onSomething};
               />
             </div>
           );
         }
    }

    Page.propTypes = {
      onAdd: PropTypes.func,
    };

    export function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return {
        onAdd: evt => {
          dispatch(fetchAdd());
        },
      };
    }

const withConnect = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
);

const withReducer = injectReducer({ key: 'page', reducer });
const withSaga = injectSaga({ key: 'page', saga });

export default compose(
  withReducer,
  withSaga,
  withConnect,
)(Page);
```

I am getting error, that: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAdd' of undefined`

Maybe someone know what I am doing bad?

Comment: You never connect the component AFAICT. You just randomly export the `mapDispatchToProps` function and that's it.

Comment: @DaveNewton, okay I will edit code. I am connecting.

Comment: @PrEto You didn't **connect** `Page` component still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just lacking the `this` context in your `onSomething` function. You can bind it either in the constructor, through class properties or as an arrow function in your jsx

```
export class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.onSomething = this.onSomething.bind(this);
  }
  // ...
};
```

or class properties (needs babel-plugin)

```
export class Page extends React.Component {
  onSomething = () => {
    this.props.onAdd();
  }
  // ...
};
```

or through arrow function in JSX

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <List
        SomeMethod={() => this.onSomething()};
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is a problem, every new comer faces and ask here. But this is very well explained in the React official doc, and no body read it there. Very strange. Every day I see at least 3 questions coming here on this issue.

Comment: @Icepickel, Thank you very much!